# 1px TD width not working

Tags: html, css

I have a 100px table cells and I am trying to fit a smaller table with 60 * 1px cells inside each of the outer cells

Could someone tell me why the green stripes are overflowing into the next TD

```
.innerStyle td {

        border-width:0px;
        border-collapse: collapse ; 

    }
```

Comment: The `td` has a padding of `1px` on each side.

Comment: FYI `bgcolor` was [deprecated in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor).

Comment: The tds are self closed but also with closing tds in the wrong place: `<td bgcolor="#00FF00"/>
                            <td bgcolor="#00FF00"/>
                            <td bgcolor="#00FF00"/>
                            <td/>
                            <td/>
                            <td/>`.  I have also found that if I wanted a 1px cell, I would have to insert a 1px image into it rather than an empty cell or a space as the cell would fill up to the size of the space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of spacing and probably padding. In ye olde days of HTML tables one would fix this by using

```
<table spacing="0" padding="0">
```

but nowadays this is possible to do with CSS.

```
.innerStyle td {
    padding:0;margin:0;
    ...
}
```